# Prevent dhcpcd from setting hostname

Tags: linux, gentoo, dhcp, hostname

How to prevent dhcpcd from setting hostname got from server? Change of it breaks a lot of things (including X session).

My current distribution is Gentoo, init system is systemd and dhcpcd is spawn by networkmanager.

Comment: Try using [this](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-840467-start-0.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From n.m.'s link - the solution is described on [NM webpage](https://wiki.gnome.org/NetworkManager/SystemSettings#Persistent_Hostname) under 'Persistent Hostname'. One need to add to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
 [main]
 plugins=keyfile

 [keyfile]
 hostname=deepspace9
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should add smth like following to your `/etc/conf.d/net`:

```
dhcpcd_eth0="-h yourhostname -H yourhostname"
```

P.S. You may want to check:

- http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=4&chap=3#doc_chap3
- http://www.phystech.com/download/dhcpcd_man.html

P.P.S. Personally I use `dhclient` because `dhcpcd` looks buggy for me.

Comment: Dhcpcd is spawned by NM so I cannot control the flags passed. Besides I use systemd so openrc's configuration flags are not applicable for that reason as well.