# NetworkManager interferes with hostname configuration

Tags: systemd, networkmanager, dhcp, hostname

I'm running an arch system with KDE4/Plasma, wpa_supplicant, networkmanager, systemd ...

```
# cat /proc/version  
Linux version 5.0.0-arch1-1-ARCH (builduser@heftig-18825) (gcc version 8.2.1 20181127 (GCC)) #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 4 14:11:43 UTC 2019
```

The content of my `/etc/hostname` reads `localhost`. 
After boot, the shell command `hostname` now outputs `localhost`. More precisely:

```
# hostnamectl 
   Static hostname: localhost
Transient hostname: localhost.localdomain
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: 7e0a101cd2f0406497a6e4354fc9b3b7
           Boot ID: a1424a0995da4e84b1e55b7f79df957e
  Operating System: Arch Linux
            Kernel: Linux 5.0.0-arch1-1-ARCH
      Architecture: x86-64
```

When I turn on WiFi, networkmanager connects to a WiFi network and then the hostname changes. For instance:

```
# hostnamectl 
   Static hostname: localhost
Transient hostname: localhost.localdomain
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: 7e0a101cd2f0406497a6e4354fc9b3b7
           Boot ID: a1424a0995da4e84b1e55b7f79df957e
  Operating System: Arch Linux
            Kernel: Linux 5.0.0-arch1-1-ARCH
      Architecture: x86-64
```

The shell command `hostname` now outputs `localhost.localdomain` instead of `localhost`.

As a consequence, the KDE lock-screen cannot be unlocked and I cannot start any X applications from the terminal in KDE (or any other desktop). A typical error message is this:

```
$ gvim
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyE233: cannot open display
```

When I issue `hostnamectl set-hostname localhost` as root, the behavior resumes to normal.

In some other WiFis, the hostname after connect is not `localhost.localdomain` but something even more random (it seems to be a hostname determined by the WiFi provider, mostly in big corporate networks). Why does a WiFi provider have the power to set my hostname? 
Can this be changed somehow?

Comment: That is a DHCP "feature" and not from Wifi per se. Depending on the DHCP daemon, some of those configurations can be ignored. TDLR It is a feature, not a bug. But it is not supposed to interfere with X.

Comment: Ah thank you! What, by the way, does TDLR mean? 
Is it possible to configure DHCP in a way that it doesn't change the hostname?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Ivanivan's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/513390/377345) (tuning `dhcpcd.con`), though plausible, didn't work in my case. So I suspect it is not about DHCP. I stumbled upon [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85276/prevent-dhcpcd-from-setting-hostname) which told me that the problem is not about DHCP but about NetworkManager. Adding the following to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` solved the problem for me:

```
[main]
plugins=keyfile 
hostname-mode=none
```

See `man 5 NetworkManager.conf` for details on the `hostname-mode` option. Setting it to `none` prevents NetworkManager from setting a transient hostname which is what happened in my case.

Comment: This worked flawlessly, even without the `plugins=keyfile` line.

Answer (score 2):

Several potential ways to fix it.  It could be that you have a `localhost` entry in `/etc/hosts` (like everything else on the planet) but you do not have a `localhost.localdomain` entry.  Adding one, also pointing to 127.0.0.1, may be a fix for your "at home" issue - but not for the "random" seeming ones you get on the "large corporate" networks.

The "better" option though is to check your dhcp client configuration.  In `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` (or it may be `dhcpcd.conf` depending on distro) look for the `request` line(s) -

```
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;
```

And simply remove the `host-name` option.